# Get Time difference between actual time and not after value

Tags: powershell, ssl

I'm using the following powershell script on CentOS to get notafter date of a certificate ssl and I want to get the difference in time between the notafter date and the actual date and I could not get how it's done. I tried the following code and it did not work and it shows me the following error

> New-TimeSpan : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.DateTime' 
>   required by parameter 'End'. Specified method is not supported.

Below is the code that I wrote

```
$certsdir = '/etc/ssl/certs/'
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $certsdir
foreach ($file in $files) { 
# Nom du fichier avec extension
$fullname = $file.Name

# Extension du fichier
$extension = $file.Extension
Write-Host $extension

# Nom du fichier sans extension
$filename = $file.BaseName
Write-Host $filename

if ($extension -eq ".crt") {
    Write-Host "ok"
    openssl x509 -inform p7b -in /etc/ssl/certs/$fullname -out $(Join-Path - 
    Path $certsdir -ChildPath "$filename.pem")
    $vars = "$filename.pem"
    $vice = get-childitem /etc/ssl/certs/$vars
    Write-Host ((& openssl x509 -in $vice -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter')
    }
    elseif ($extension -eq ".der") {
    Write-Host "ok"
    openssl x509 -inform p7b -in /etc/ssl/certs/$fullname -out $(Join-Path - 
    Path $certsdir -ChildPath "$filename.pem")
    $vars = "$filename.pem"
    $vice = get-childitem /etc/ssl/certs/$vars
    $timessl = ((& openssl x509 -in $vice -dates -noout) -match 'notAfter')
    $timenow = Get-Date
    $diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $timenow -End $timessl 
    Write-Host $diff

}
}
```

Comment: please add the source/target date format...

Comment: sorry I did not understand

Comment: without seeing the EXACT content of `$timessl` there is no way to determine the exact problem. the _general_ problem is parsing the _date string_ into a _datetime object_, but any more detailed analysis requires seeing the data involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `-match` with an *array*<sup>[1]</sup> as the LHS, the results is invariably also an array - even if only *one* element matches.

Therefore, you must pass the resulting one-element array's *first element* to `New-TimeSpan`:

```
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $timenow -End $timessl[0]
```

Given that `$timessl[0]` contains a *string*, the command will only work if `New-TimeSpan` recognizes that string's date/time format.

In your case, as you state in a comment, `$timessl[0]` contains something like
`notAfter=Feb 7 16:10:41 2021 GMT`, which is *not* directly recognized (even without the `notAfter=` part), so you must parse the string explicitly, as [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) and [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) suggest:

```
$diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $timenow -End [datetime]::ParseExact(
  ($timessl[0] -replace '^notAfter='), 
  'MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy GMT',
   [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
)
```

---

<sup>[1] When you capture the (stdout) output from an external program and that output contains more than one line, PowerShell returns an *array* of strings, each representing an output line.</sup>